# How to prevent content jumping up when resizing browser?

Tags: css, image

The image caption and content is held in place by the image. When window is resized or image is loading the page content jumps up and is then jumps back down again.

Is it possible to prevent the content from moving in this way?

```
<div class="profile">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/720/720/nature" alt="" />
</div>
```

See https://codepen.io/atoms/pen/bRdLVe

Built on Chris Ferdinandi's Kraken CSS framework.

This seems to do the trick:

```
.profile {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    float: left;
    height: 0;
    }
.profile img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    }
```

and the result: 
https://codepen.io/atoms/pen/jwbOYe

Now when you reload the page the text stays in place even when the image has not yet loaded. And you can resize the browser window to reflow the contents with the same result.

Not sure if the CSS is entirely correct but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can add a class to your caption, like following:

```
<p class="image-caption"><small>Image caption</small></p>
```

And then add a "hidden" class in CSS:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Then use jQuery to implement this feature:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(".image-caption").addClass("hidden");
    $(".profile img").on('load', function() {
      $(".image-caption").removeClass("hidden");
    })
});
```

Note: you need to include jQuery in your HTML code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you @charles-wei — managed to find a css solution which will hopefully work.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on if you are going to have consistent image sizes or not. If your images will always be the same size in that spot, you can set a CSS height of the image size on the image (or even your profile div) and that will create the space on the page before the image loads, preventing the jump.

```
.profile img { height:250px }
```

If your images will vary in size and you need to avoid distortion, a JS approach like also mentioned here might be a better approach.

Comment: It is the same image but once content rearranges in dynamic layout there would effectively be two sizes.